# How to compare a three dimensional array with a two dimensional array in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a three-dimensional array of shape `(height, width, 3)`, it represents an BGR image, the values are floats in [0, 1].

After some operation on the pixels I obtain a two-dimensional array of shape `(height, width)`, the values in the array are the results of some operation performed on each individual pixel.

Now I want to compare the original image with the result, more specifically I want to compare each of the BGR components of each pixel with the value of the result array located at the same coordinate.

For instance, I want to know which of the BGR component is the greatest in each pixel:

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.random.random((360, 640, 3))
maxa = img.max(axis=-1)
```

Now I want to compare `img` with `maxa`, I know `img == maxa` doesn't work:

```
In [335]: img == maxa
<ipython-input-335-acb909814b9a>:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  img == maxa
Out[335]: False
```

I am not good at describing things, so I will show you what I intend to do in Python:

```
result = [[[c == maxa[y, x] for c in img[y, x]] for x in range(640)] for y in range(360)]
```

Obviously it is inefficient but I want to demonstrate I know the logic.

I have managed to do the same in NumPy, but I think it can be more efficient:

```
img == np.dstack([maxa, maxa, maxa])
```

I have confirmed my comprehension's correctness:

```
In [339]: result = [[[c == maxa[y, x] for c in img[y, x]] for x in range(640)] for y in range(360)]
     ...: np.array_equal(arr3, img == np.dstack([maxa, maxa, maxa]))
Out[339]: True
```

And I have benchmarked my methods:

```
In [340]: %timeit [[[c == maxa[y, x] for c in img[y, x]] for x in range(640)] for y in range(360)]
509 ms ± 16.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [341]: maxals = maxa.tolist()

In [342]: imgls = img.tolist()

In [343]: %timeit [[[c == maxals[y][x] for c in imgls[y][x]] for x in range(640)] for y in range(360)]
156 ms ± 2.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [344]: %timeit img == np.dstack([maxa, maxa, maxa])
4.25 ms ± 121 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

What is a faster method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you want:

```py
img == np.dstack([maxa, maxa, maxa])
```

Then this is how you do it:

```py
img == maxa[..., np.newaxis]
```

Numpy broadcasting rules mean that outer dimensions are added as-required but not inner dimensions. That means you can compare shapes `[x, y, z]` with shape `[y, z]` (for all `x`, do …) but not `[x, y]` (for all `z`, do …). However, an inner dimension can be set to 1, allowing appropriate broadcasting. This is what we do with `np.newaxis`. It turns the `[x, y]` shape into `[x, y, 1]`.

The deprecation warning was just for comparing arrays of incompatible shape and getting a `False` return value; not for using `==` with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are correct in that the typical numpy way to do this is via broadcasting. However, there's no need for `np.newaxis`!

"Reducing" operations (`np.sum`, `np.max`, [`np.ufunc.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) etc.) all have a keyword argument `keepdims` for this purpose. [From the `np.max` docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.max.html) (emphasis mine):

> `keepdims` -  `bool, optional`
>
> If this is set to True, the axes which are reduced are left in the result as dimensions with size one. **With this option, the result will broadcast correctly against the original array.**

So regardless of which axis you reduce, the following will always work:

```
import numpy as np

# No matter which axis
axis = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2])

img = np.random.random((360, 640, 3))
maxa = img.max(axis=axis, keepdims=True)

img == maxa
```

To illustrate the key difference:

```
>>> img.max(axis=-1).shape
(360, 640)
>>> img.max(axis=-1, keepdims=True).shape
(360, 640, 1)
```

Comment: I saw this parameter before but never gave it much thought. elegant!